# Modifying a Python dictionary from different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, dictionary, locking

When it comes to threading, I know you have to make sure you're not editing a variable at the same time another thread is editing it, as your changes can be lost (when incrementing a counter, for example)

Does the same apply to dictionaries? Or is a dictionary a collection of variables?

If every thread were to lock the dictionary it would slow the program down significantly, while every thread only needs write access to its own little piece of the dictionary.

If it isn't possible, is there some sort of variable variable in python, like in php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you misundertood this whole thread safety thing. It's not so much about variables (or variable variables - those are terrible anyway, and are just as pointless - not to say harmful - here as in every other case) but about -- for example, there are many nasty nasty ways threading can go wrong; they all come from accessing something mutable from more than one thread at overlapping times -- this:

- thread N gets data from source (some place in memory or on disk - a variable, a slot in a dictionary, a file, pretty much anything mutable)
- thread M gets data from source
- thread N modifies the data
- thread M modifies the data
- thread N overwrites source with modified data
- thread M overwrites source with modified data
- Result: thread N's modifications are lost/the new shared value doesn't take thread N's modifications into account

And it applies to dictionaries and variable variables (which are just a horrible, horrible language-level implementation of dicts with string-only keys) as well. The only solutions are not using shared state to begin with (functional languages do this by discouraging or even completely disallowing mutability, and it works well for them) or adding some sort of locking to everything shared (hard to get right, but if you get it right, at least it works correctly). If no two threads every share anything in that dictionary, you're fine - but you should seperate everything, to be (a bit more) sure that they really don't share anything.

Comment: Indeed. And should thread N AND M would modify data['a'] that would happen, but what if thread N modifies data['a'] and thread M modifies data['b']? Would that still happen? And what can be done without locking the dictionary?

Comment: @skerit: As I wrote, no. They don't interfere with each other. Of course you can't be sure they really never overlap if they share the dictionary...

Comment: Oh right, I see. "a slot in a dictionary". Then I only have to lock the dictionary when adding or deleting a key, as that would cause exceptions when something is iterating over it.

Comment: I wonder if there are any plans for implementing eventual consistency to use cases that can tolerate them, in terms of threads and locking. So, if you can tolerate stale data and get better performance, you would use that.

Answer (score 26):

> Does the same apply to dictionaries? Or is a dictionary a collection of variables?

Let's be more general:

**What does "atomic operation" mean?**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation) :

> In concurrent programming, an
>   operation (or set of operations) is
>   atomic, linearizable, indivisible or
>   uninterruptible if it appears to the
>   rest of the system to occur
>   instantaneously. Atomicity is a
>   guarantee of isolation from concurrent
>   processes.

**Now what does this mean in Python?**

This means that each bytecode instruction is atomic (at least for Python <3.2, before the new GIL).

**Why  is that???**

Because Python (CPython) use a [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). The CPython interpreter uses a lock to make sure that only one thread runs in the interpreter at a time, and uses a "check interval" (see [`sys.getcheckinterval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getcheckinterval)) to know how many bytecode instructions to execute before switching between threads (by default set to 100).

**So now what does this mean??**

It means that operations that can be represented by only one bytecode instruction are atomic. For example, incrementing a variable is *not* atomic, because the operation is done in three bytecode instructions:

```
>>> import dis

>>> def f(a):
        a += 1

>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)      <<<<<<<<<<<< Operation 1 Load
              6 INPLACE_ADD                         <<<<<<<<<<<< Operation 2 iadd
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)      <<<<<<<<<<<< Operation 3 store
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

**So what about dictionaries??**

Some operations are atomic; for example, this operation is atomic:

```
d[x] = y
d.update(d2)
d.keys()
```

See for yourself:

```
>>> def f(d):
        x = 1
        y = 1
        d[x] = y

>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (y)

  4          12 LOAD_FAST                2 (y)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             21 STORE_SUBSCR                      <<<<<<<<<<< One operation 
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_SUBSCR) to understand what STORE_SUBSCR does.

But as you see, it is not totally true, because this operation:

```
             ...
  4          12 LOAD_FAST                2 (y)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             ...
```

can make the entire operation not atomic. Why? Let's say the variable x can also be changed by another thread...or that you want another thread to clear your dictionary...we can name many cases when it can go wrong, so it is complicated! And so here we will apply [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy_law): "Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong".

**So what now?**

If you still want to share variables between thread, use a lock:

```
import threading

mylock = threading.RLock()

def atomic_operation():
    with mylock:
        print "operation are now atomic"
```

Comment: Thanks for being thorough. Have you heard if anyone has implemented an eventual consistency layer on top of threading? So use cases that can tolerate stale data can get better performance, that is.

Comment: @HeyWatchThis: Hi, not that i am aware of, sorry :(, but probably now the big new think is green thread (back from the past :)) see library like gevent, eventlet ... that may simplify threading for you specially if you have a I/O bound process, else you still have the multiprocessing option which is advocate by most dynamic language that have GIL (like Python, Ruby) or maybe new shinning think like transactional memory from pypy, experimental only :) Else if you want performant concurrent code look to Erlang or such ... Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to not allow the threads direct access to the shared data structure but instead wrap access to it with something that guarantees mutual exclusion like a [mutex](http://docs.python.org/library/mutex.html).

Making access to the original structure look the same (`shared[id] = value`) takes some more work, but not that much.